# Triangle of numbers

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

You can place each number from 1 to 10 into a triangle, such that each number below the first row is the absolute difference of the two numbers above it:

```
8  10   1   6
  2   9   5
    7   4
      3
```

Now can you do the same with numbers from 1 to 15?

Good luck!

Comment: This question has already been asked and solved :-)

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49877/difference-triangle